# Two threads adding objects to ArrayList: can't output the size: Why does removing println lead to an infinite loop

Tags: java, concurrency

I have this program:

**Farmer.java**:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Farmer implements Runnable  {
  List<Apple> busket;
  private static int count;
  private int id;
  private int appleCount;

  public Farmer(List<Apple> busket)  {
    this.busket = busket;
    id = count++;
  }

  public void makeApple()  {
    Apple apple = new Apple("Apple" + appleCount + " by Farmer"+id);
    System.out.println("making apple: " + apple);

    busket.add(apple);
    appleCount++;
  }

  public void run()  {
    while (appleCount<5)  {
      makeApple();
    }
  }
}
```

**Apple.java**:

```
public class Apple  {
  private String name;

  public String getName() {return name;}

  public String toString() {return name;}

  public Apple(String name)  {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

**Main.java**:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Hello world!");

    List<Apple> apples = new ArrayList<>();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Farmer(apples));
    t1.start();

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Farmer(apples));
    t2.start();

    while (apples.size()==0) {
  //    System.out.println(apples.size());
    }

    System.out.println(apples.size());
}
}
```

it gives this output:

```
Hello world!
making apple: Apple0 by Farmer1
making apple: Apple1 by Farmer1
making apple: Apple2 by Farmer1
making apple: Apple3 by Farmer1
making apple: Apple4 by Farmer1
making apple: Apple0 by Farmer0
making apple: Apple1 by Farmer0
making apple: Apple2 by Farmer0
making apple: Apple3 by Farmer0
making apple: Apple4 by Farmer0
```

so it never prints

```
System.out.println(apples.size());
```

however if I uncomment

```
//    System.out.println(apples.size());
```

inside while loop

I get this output:

```
...many more zeroes
0
0
0
making apple: Apple0 by Farmer1
0
0
...a bit more zeroes
1
making apple: Apple0 by Farmer0
making apple: Apple1 by Farmer0
making apple: Apple2 by Farmer0
making apple: Apple3 by Farmer0
making apple: Apple4 by Farmer0
making apple: Apple1 by Farmer1
making apple: Apple2 by Farmer1
making apple: Apple3 by Farmer1
making apple: Apple4 by Farmer1
```

you can see the

```
1
```

in the above output, which is the size of the array.

and the program never seems to stop.

I also tried this loop:

```
    int i=0;
    while (apples.size()==0) {
      System.out.println("i: " + i); //works as previous: if uncommented, there's size output later, if commented out, no size output, program keeps running
    }
```

and

```
    int i=0;
    while (apples.size()==0) {
      //System.out.println("i: " + i);
      i++; //doesn't influence - no size output unless uncomment system.out.println
    }
```

and it has the same behaviour

Why is this behaviour? Why adding the print statement inside the while loop gives correct output (array's size and the finishing of the program), while removing it seems to get the program stuck in the while loop even though the array gets filled?

**EDIT**:

I know it can be solved with using a synchronized list. I want to understand why this behaves the way it does, not fix the code.

Comment: I see no attempt to ensure thread safety. `ArrayList` is not thread safe. "[_Note that this implementation is not synchronized._](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html)"

Comment: And the print statement, because it uses a system stream, implicitly adds synchronization.

Comment: Try this `List<Apple> apples = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick TL;DR solution: Insert some `synchronized` statements to protect access to the shared list already!

---

Java doesn't guarantee that things will work correctly when more than one thread accesses the same variable *without being explicitly synchronized*.

In the case where you have

```
while (apples.size()==0) {
    //    System.out.println(apples.size());
}
```

the JIT is allowed to

1. inline the body of `apples.size()` which most likely just reads a private variable in the list object, and
2. then emit code that *reads the variable only once* from the heap and keep testing the copy of the size that it stored in a register once and for all. Nothing the other threads do will change this locally cached copy of the size information. So because the length of the list *started* at 0, that's what the test will see forever -- you have an infinite loop.

The JIT is allowed to do that because Java's concurrency model says that a thread is not guaranteed to be able to see changes to a heap field that another thread makes, *until* both threads have passed through some appropriate synchronization actions.

When you insert the call to `System.out.println()` what happens is that the body of the loop is now so complex that the JIT cannot prove that `System.out.println()` will not *somehow* change things inside the list object. (*We* can see easily that it won't but the JIT is a bear of very little brain and cannot). Therefore it doesn't dare share the value of the size field it read in the previous iteration of the loop; instead it creates machine code that will read the size field from the heap object once for each time around the loop. Therefore -- but definitely more by accident than by design! -- your main thread *will* eventually pick up the changes from the other threads.

---

This doesn't mean everything is now fine, because you still have two different threads trying to modify the `ArrayList` and nothing to prevent them from stepping on each other's toes. All manner of strange things may go wrong then. It *may just* happen to work as you intended. Or, if you're really lucky, you may get a nice explicit `ConcurrentModificationException` thrown in one of the threads. Or one or more of the apples may silently be lost, or you may encounter `NullPointerException` or worse if you later try to take the apples *out* of the list again.

Comment: I like the answer, very detailed. Im curious if you used any tool to analyze what exactly is happening under the hood or if it is just a very educated guess that this is indeed what happens here and not another random quirk of the memory model.

Comment: @Zabuza: It's just an educated guess, based on experience with how compilers tend to behave in similar situations.

Comment: Fairly sure you could _never_ get a `ConcurrentModificationException` from unsafe multithreaded access...

Comment: `Or one or more of the apples may silently be lost, or you may encounter NullPointerException or worse if you later try to take the apples out of the list again`, going by the ArrayList's source code, do I understand correctly that such can happen when the array gets filled, so one thread adding a new apple triggers its expansion (in thread main), but just as it's being expanded, a second thread adds its own apple, so the array gets expanded by the second thread (in thread main), so the expanding of the array by the first thread gets stopped and the first thread's apple gets lost?

Comment: @CyberWolf: Those predictions are not based on the particular source code -- since the implementation is provided by the JRE it's possible that long after you've deployed your code, it will suddenly be running against a different implementation. with different particular possble outcomes of racing against another copy of itself. You really can't depend on anything other than what the contract of the class promises you.

Comment: @CyberWolf: In this particular case, a very easy-to-imagine scenario even without an array expansion happening is (1) both threads concurrently read the _current_ size of the list, (2) both threads now try to write their apple into the same slot in the array; one if them will win that; (3) each thread separately adds one to the length they read and writes the same _new_ size of the list to the size field.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the ArrayList creation to a Synchronized object will do the trick since the original ArrayList implementation is not thread safe or you may use Vector.

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Hello world!");

    List<Apple> apples = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

    //Or
    //List<Apple> apples = new Vector<>();

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Farmer(apples));
    t1.start();

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Farmer(apples));
    t2.start();

    while (apples.size()==0) {
  //    System.out.println(apples.size());
    }

    System.out.println(apples.size());
}
}
```